# How to efficiently store large amount of addresses in a smart contract using solidity?

Tags: storage, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am developing a smart contract where users need to deposit funds. Something similar to the DeFi projects. I am still new in solidity development and was wondering can you recommend to me an efficient way to store those user addresses? I found a similar question where I understood that storing them in an array is not very efficient, because when I iterate through it, it will be very costly. I saw other recommendations for using Maps, which are good alternatives, however, I don't know whether they will solve my issue.

My idea is to create a smart contract ->  store user's addresses who interact/deposit funds -> transfer those addresses to another smart contract that is going to pay interest, etc.

I assume most of the DeFi projects should have resolved that, because they need to store the addresses of their users, so can you give me some tips on how it is done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the combinations of mapping. Mapping is like an object in javascript or a dictionary in python.

You want to keep track of addresses that deposits. for this, you might still need to keep them in an array for different purposes.

```
// keep private and then set a getter.
address[] private fundersAddresses;
```

also set a mapping to keep track of the index to address. for this, I can also set a variable to keep track of index of array

```
// you could call fundersAddresses.length and it's time complexity most likely O(1)  but since I am not 100% sure, I set up a index variable 
uint256 private index; 
mapping(uint256=>address) private indexToAddress
```

Now if you write a function to store the funders

```
function storeFunders() public payable {
   // add some logic
   fundersAddresses.push(msg.sender);
   index++;
   // then also store in a mapping
  
   indexToAddress[index]=msg.sender    
}
```

Now if you want to get the i'th item in an array, it will take O(1) time because you will look up the mapping instead of calling `array[i]`. `array[i]`'s time complexity is O(n) because ethereum engine would iterate over array till the i'th index.

```
function getIndexedAddress (uint index) public returns(address){
    require(index<fundersAddresses.length,"Index out of bounds")
    return indexToAddress[index]  
}
```

This is just a simple example. Based on the needs of your contract you might set up different structure.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I get the idea, however have a small question. In my case I want to build 2 smart contracts. First will be for depositing money and second for paying the interest rate. Therefore if you are a user who has deposited Ethers in the first SC and now want to get the interest rate from the second, do you need to know your index? How I imagine it is, you go to the 2nd SC and call a function that needs to verify whether you have deposited money, otherwise you won't be allowed to withdraw.

Comment: Therefore if the 2nd smart contract has access to the mapping of addresses stored in the 1st, it means that the users who are calling it need to know their indexes. That is how the SC will compare whether msg.sender == indexToAddress[index] because the user will pretend to be an address who has already made a deposit.

Comment: I used `index` to show you how to tackle the looping an array. Based on your contract you might apply different logic. in your case you might create a struct with id, address, isInterestPaid fields. then keep track of addresses by struct id. For other questions it is better to ask a separate question in detail. answering comments on comment is not fun

Answer (score 1):

If the addresses are final at the deployment, you can use a Merkle tree.

Comment: even if they are not final at deployment, you could have Merkle tree roothash update function (by owner) in contract, anyway Merkle tree is smartest approach and will save a lot of gas, I support

Comment: Agreed with you.